# TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image:

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf and this code for style custom header:

```
  $pdf->setHeaderData($ln='', $lw=0, $ht='', $hs='
        <table style="padding-bottom: 10px; width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td width="120">
                    <img src="'.base_url('assets/img/logo.png').'"/ style="width: 100px; margin-right: 70px;">
                </td>
                <td style="padding-top: -50px;">
                    <span style="font-size:27px; color: #ED1B23; margin-top: -35px;">PT Malindo Feedmill Tbk</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><hr>', $tc=array(0,0,0), $lc=array(0,0,0));
```

this code is working in localhost, but when I put to server this code does not work, in server I have enable file_get_contents and install cURL.

this is the error message:

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image: http://domain/assets/img/logo.png
```

Comment: try to use relative URL instead of the absolute. It should resolve your problems.

Comment: @Jakuje I have try to change to relative URL still not working